# Non propositional grand narratives and postmodernism?

Tags: postmodernism

So I understand the post modernism pushed back against grand narratives. Can postmodernism attack grand narratives which do not structure themselves with propositions? Or is it just more difficult?

Comment: Well, one of the grandest narratives is morality and [non-cognitivists](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/moral-cognitivism/) hold that it is not structured with propositions. That did not stop Nietzsche from pushing back against it, indeed, it was an integral part of it. And he was one of postmodernism's chief inspirations. The whole rage against the "tyranny of truth/knowledge" and the like involves  "exposing" seemingly propositional narratives as covert power plays. And without an aura of propositionality and truth it becomes only so much easier to attack a narrative as corrupt.

Comment: I don't understand how any narrative could be structured without propositions. We can tell stories in pictures, I suppose, and music. But to tell a story, they both need a good deal of support from propositions. An example would help.

Comment: The comment above (conifold) gives one. Then there those who claim to know some deep truth through arduous religious practices (like Zen) which is inexpressible in language. Yo paraphrase: if I point to the moon don't look at my finger but the heavenly body